# Why doesn't R check for missing arguments at start of call?

Tags: r

I noticed that R functions check for missing arguments only at the time when the specific argument is evaluated in the function body.

Example:

```
f <- function(x, y) {
    Sys.sleep(3)
    return(x + y)
}
f(1)
```

The function takes 3 seconds to fail and report the missing argument rather that at the start of the function call. What is the advantage of such an implementation?

EDIT:

I'm aware of force() and missing(). I would like to know what the advantage is of missing() on an argument immediately before evaluation rather than at the start of a function call. Is there a necessary reason for such an implementation?

As a contrived example

```
f2 <- function() {
    Sys.sleep(3)
}

f <- function(x, y) {
    if (missing(y)) stop("y missing")
    print(x)
}

f(1, f2())
```

The "expensive" call to f2() is still avoided by lazy evaluation, but its missingness can be checked without evaluation.

EDIT2:

I guess you can argue that it gives more flexibility for generating default values, in another contrived example

```
f <- function(x, y = 1:3) {
    if (missing(x)) {
        x <- y
    }
    x
}

f()
```

such code would fail if argument checking was done immediately upon function call. However this code is better written as `function(x = y, y = 1:3)`. Though I guess such a feature would be used by a non-trivial number of codebases and changing the behaviour now would be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: R is a scripted, not a compiled, language.  Many other things also only fail at runtime, e.g. type safety issues.  And when I [run your example script](http://rextester.com/QWSQVQ35038) I most definitely get back error feedback which tells me what happened.

Comment: Sorry I'll edit the question to make it clear. I'm pointing to the fact that it does not fail until the variable y is actually evaluated in the body of the function, I'm not seeing any reason why missingness of arguments isn't checked at the start of the function call.

Comment: Lazy evaluation is a feature. It makes many calls faster.

Comment: Is it not possible to check missingness without full evaluation of an expression? I feel like the existence of an argument is independent of whether or what the value actually is. Does Haskell's lazy evaluation produce similar results?

Comment: You can use `missing()`

Comment: I've edited my question with thoughts on the topic. In my opinion it's an idiosyncrasy of R rather than a well motivated design choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> R uses lazy evaluation. That is, arguments to functions are not evaluated until
>   they are required. This can save both time and memory if it turns out the
>   argument is not required.
>   In extremely rare circumstances something is not evaluated that should be.
>   You can use `force` to get around the laziness.

Burns, Patrick. 2011. « The R Inferno ». http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf.

So, this following code will fail faster :

```
f <- function(x, y) {
 force(y)
 Sys.sleep(3)
 return(x + y)
}
f(1)
```

or

```
f <- function(x, y) {
  if(missing(y)) stop("missing y")
  Sys.sleep(3)
  return(x + y)
}
f(1)
```

Comment: My question is really why it's implemented so you have to do the missingness check manually, but I'm wondering why automatic checking at the start of the function isn't the default behaviour. I guess I'm looking for any kind of mailing list discussion related to this choice.

Comment: Again, it's a feature. Sometimes you want the convenience of being able to call a function with missing arguments. Many functions are implemented in a way allowing this.

Comment: Would you mind posting an example of one of these many functions as an answer and showing why it is necessary?